# Showing more information while decluttering the screen

Tags: menu, toolbar

I'm designing an educational app with gamified elements to it. The way the app has evolved the left side is what we consider the most important information for the user. The items to the right are all considered of equal weight.

The first prototype shows the toolbar/header as this:

[image]

I find it very cluttered, and I'm wondering how I can show more information while decluttering...

The ideas I have thought of:

1. Have another bordered cell to the right and have a constant rotation between the secondary items, like this:

[image]

Something like this, clicking on the cell brings up a menu for the user to navigate to all items individual screens.

2. Maybe something more experimental.. I'm not sure about this one

[image]

I'm curious what y'all think on the best practices in this situation..

Thank you

Comment: what does the blue bar indicate, and is there a reason you've encapsulated it? Also, are the 3 other elements clickable? what is their function. If you can provide more context of what functions they allow it could be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Your design looks confusing for the simple reason that it isn't clear why some element are on the left, why some are on the right, and why some are stacked.

It would be better to just keep them all together and consistent. Once your user learns what each icon represents, they will mentally be able to put their own importance on each icon. Keeping them all close together means the user only needs to look in one spot for the information they need.

Also, you icons and colours are quite distinct so it should be easy for the user to differentiate the values without you having to worry about spacing them out too much.

Something like this:

[image]

---

Additionally, look at the header bar on the top of this very site. The rep and badges are together. They are clear and obvious without needing to take up a lot of space.